# How do I use for loop with zip to combine two lists into separate sentences

Tags: loops, for-loop, zip

I have:

`cities = ["Phoenix", "Austin", "San Diego", "New York"]`

`states = ["Arizona", "Texas", "California", "New York"]`

and I want to use for loop and zip to get:

Phoenix is in Arizona

Austin is in Texas

San Diego is in California

New York is in New York

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue.

```js
    const cities = ["Phoenix", "Austin", "San Diego", "New York"];
    const states = ["Arizona", "Texas", "California", "New York"];

    for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
      console.log(cities[i] + "is in " + states[i])
    }
```

You could also combine the two arrays into one.

```js
    const cities = ["Phoenix", "Austin", "San Diego", "New York"];
    const states = ["Arizona", "Texas", "California", "New York"];
    const zip = cities.map((city, index) => [city, states[index]]);

    for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
      console.log(zip[i][0] + "is in " + zip[i][1])
    }
```